# Wrapping ViewGroup 'tightly' around scaling ImageView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview

I have a layout that includes two big images with some overlay.

On top of the image, there is a semitransparent background. This is where the problem lies:

The images are in the horizontal center of the layout, with `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`. This is how the images are displayed correctly. The semitransparent background however occupies the full width of the layout, not restricting itself to the imageview. I would like is semitransparent bar to only occupy the width of the image.

How could I get the semitransparent part to only occupy the with of the image, preferrably only with XML?

[image: Current situation with too broad overlays]

The current XML layout (resulting in image above):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#222">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/test_img_1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

        <View android:id="@+id/blur_user"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Some text"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/user_choice"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/test_img_1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

        <View android:id="@+id/blur_installer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Some text"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/installer_choice"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya: Setting the scaleType to `fitXY` doesn't make a difference as far as I can see. Could you elaborate?

Comment: set `android:layout_width="match_parent"`  in `RelativeLayout` and `ImageView`section .for test case comment `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya: This causes the images to be stretched. The images as they are shown in the question are shown correct, the problem is with the semitransparent overlay.

Comment: There is no way to achieve this using only xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a lot of trial and error, but it all resulted in no result. As @Msk said in the comments, there seems to be no way to achieve this using only XML. So I've solved it by adding these lines to the `onCreateView` method. It listens to when the image is drawn, and adjusts the blur accordingly.

```
    image.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            image.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = blurView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.width = image.getWidth();
            blurView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
```